# Tricky child selector

Tags: jquery, html, selector

It's a simple question but I can't get it done. I tried a lot of different ways, including these ones http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

In this case:

**HTML**

```
<div id="quiz_list_wrap"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div id=level>bla bla
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click","#quiz_list_wrap .row",function(event){
    var self = $(this); // I need self for something else
    var varname = $(self > .level);
        alert(varname.html());
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not to get thumbs down! And also select the div class level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Your click handler will never be called, because the selector `"#quiz_list_wrap .row"` doesn't match anything. That selector looks for a *descendant* of `#quiz_list_wrap` that has class `row`. But you have `#quiz_list_wrap` *itself* having class `row` in your example HTML.</s> *(The updated structure in the question no longer has that problem.)*

Separately, you've given the `div` an `id`. So there can only be **one** of those in the document. To select the `div`, simply do this:

```
var levelDiv = $("#level");
```

If you *only* want to find it if it's a descendant of your `#quiz_list_wrap` element, and you only want to find it on click, you can do that with `find`:

```
$(document).on("click","#quiz_list_wrap",function(event){
// ------------------ note change -----^
    var levelDiv = $(this).find("#level");
});
```

Now, if your HTML actually looked like this (I've added a child element for `row` and changed the `id` on the level div to a `class` so you can have more than one):

```
<div id="quiz_list_wrap"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class=level>bla bla
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...then your click handler would get called with your original selector, and you'd use `$(this).find("div.level")` (or just `$(this).find(".level")`) within the handler to find it.

Finally, since you said *child* selector, I'll mention that `find` looks for any descendant (child, grandchild, etc.). If you *really* only want to look at children, use `$(this).children("selector here")` instead.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add the first child .row.. but its there.. I'll update the thread

Comment: The other guy who answered varname = $(" > .level",self); was right, but he deleted his answer after yours =(

Comment: @Th3B0Y: Looks like I guessed correctly at what your real structure is, see the update to the answer I was writing as you updated the question. I would recommend using `find` or `children` over `$("> .level", self)`, not least because the latter just turns around and calls `find` anyway.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! Actually this table has more than 1 row, so theres one #level in each row. Thats why I used $(this) in the meaning of this row.

Comment: @Th3B0Y: If there's a `#level` in each row, the document is invalid. [`id` values **must** be unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: each level has and id.. like #level1 #level2 but they share the class level